# Is the target of the Mystic's psionic effect "Occluded Mind" aware that it is being targeted?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, telepathy, mystic

[The most recent version of the Unearthed Arcana Mystic (V3) can be found here.](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf)

Mystics can learn a number of Psionic Disciplines, each of which allow them to expend psi points to create certain effects. The [Telepathic Contact](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf#page=26) psionic discipline allows the Mystic to use the Occluded Mind effect to make a creature you can telepathically communicate with believe a statement of your choice.

Is the target of the Mystic's Occluded Mind effect aware that the effect has been used on it? If so, is it aware of the source of the effect, i.e, the Mystic that cast it?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes and no.

TLDR; They would be able to work out that you did something from the context. They might not realise what you did - it depends on how well they know psionics (Arcana check).

**Reasons why they would know it is you:**

You have to speak to them telepathically to use the feature, and telepathic communication is done in your voice. It is at least obvious that you are the one telling them the lie, per an [unofficial ruling by rules designer Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/711981264740331521):

> You sound like yourself when speaking via telepathy, although as DM, I allow attempts at telepathic deception. #DnD

**Reasons why they wouldn't know it is you:**

On a failed save, there is no effect.

The mystic's Occluded Mind psionic effect says that:

> On a successful save, the target is unaffected. [...]

RAW, nothing happens. There is no effect to determine. However, if you tell them to believe something (e.g. "The sky is green"), they know that you told them, and they will at least think it is odd that you say that (e.g. "What? It's clearly blue!").

After the 5 minutes is up, and they see something to counteract your statement (the sky clearly not being green), they will realise that they believed that it was for a time, and remember you telling them that it was.

Perhaps your DM will rule that they saw the sky as being green for those 5 minutes, and remember it as such, though in any case, you are clearly the one who initiated....something: even if it was just an illusion of the sky being green.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling is to say that RAW no it isn't.

Generally the V3 Mystic Psionics are difficult to detect having no verbal, somatic, or material components but my main reasoning is when you compare this ability to the something like the [Charm Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) spell:

> You attempt to charm a humanoid you can see within range. It must make a Wisdom saving throw, and does so with advantage if you or your companions are fighting it. If it fails the saving throw, it is charmed by you until the spell ends or until you or your companions do anything harmful to it. The charmed creature regards you as a friendly acquaintance. **When the spell ends, the creature knows it was charmed by you.**

Charm Person specifically states that the creature becomes aware that it was affected by the spell.  There is no such rider attached to the Occluded Mind description, and given the above, I would have thought a similar rider would have been included if this was intended. So that's how I see it RAW.

However, I think a bit of common sense needs to be applied to this. As a DM interpreting this, I think it may also depend on how ambitious, far-fetched, or subtle the believed statement was, and how out of character such a belief would be to the to the target.

For example, if the statement was something along the lines of "You believe the Elf next to you is a deadly snake", then when the 5 minutes is up, it's going to be obvious something wasn't right when the target stops believing the Elf is a snake.

On the flip side, if the statement was something like "You believe the Elf next to you is your trusted friend", and after the 5 minutes is up, the Elf in question is no longer in sight, then I think I would take the view that the target would not be aware that they were targeted.